# How to pass a DOM element from componentDidMount() to another function defined in another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function say **ABC()** in another file to which I need to pass some DOM elements. But if store the DOM elements in another variable say **node** and then pass it to **ABC()** or if directly pass it to **ABC()**, in both the cases, **[object HTMLDivElement]** is stored/passed as a value to **ABC()** function.

This is my ABC.js file.

```
export function ABC(inputRef) {
  console.log(inputRef);        // prints [object HTMLDivElement]
  // do something
}
```

and this is my react file XYZ.js.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {ABC} from './ABC.js';
 
class PrimePage extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInputRef = null;
    this.submitBtnRef = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.submitBtnRef.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      console.log(this.textInputRef);  // prints <input type="text" id="input-check"> which I need to pass
      let node = this.textInputRef;
      console.log(node);               // prints [object HTMLDivElement]
      ABC(this.textInputRef); 
      ABC(node);
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <input type="text" id="input-check" ref={(input) => { this.textInputRef = 
        input; }}>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" ref={(input) => { 
        this.submitBtnRef = input; }}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

I want a way in which I can pass DOM elements to **ABC()** function. Basically I need a **document.getElementById("id")** like functionality so that I can manipulate HTML using **innerHTML** property inside the **ABC()** function in the ABC.js file.